# Integration of Private APIs with AWS Step function tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, aws-step-functions

We have Private APIs with API-G endpoints backed by a Lamba within a VPC and Subnet.

We also have a step function that relies on these API endpoints within the same account.

What policies should we add to allow step function invoke Private APIs  ? This is the error I see during step function executions -

```
{
  "resourceType": "apigateway",
  "resource": "invoke",
  "error": "ApiGateway.UnknownHostException",
  "cause": "[API-G].execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known"
}
```

VPC already has 443 inbound rule added to its security group. Do we need to create VPC Private link between step function and VPC ?

The integration works fine for regional public APIs. But as soon as we convert these to private, the integration fails with above error.

Note that, I am still able to invoke the APIs from the API-G console and step function execution role has permissions to invoke the APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html), the Step Functions integration with API Gateway does not support calling a private API.

> Unsupported by the Step Functions API Gateway integration:
>
> - **Authorizers**: Amazon Cognito, Native Open ID Connect / OAuth 2.0,
>   Authorization header for token-based Lambda authorizers
> - **API types**: Private
> - **API VPC  management**: Custom domain names

Despite these limitations, if calling a private API is a crucial requirement for you, there exists a more complex architectural solution.
You can facilitate the API Gateway call through a [Lambda Function situated within the VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html): you should also configure a VPC endpoint within the VPC to enable integration with private API Gateway calls (but you have probably already configured it due to its default nature in a Private API Gateway integration).